# Determinant of a non-square matrix tell you if it is non-linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose a matrix $A = $\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

How can we argue that the vectors are independent if we can't take the determinant?

Comment: What is a non-linear vector?

Comment: Non linear or independent?

Comment: Sorry independent

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that what you're asking is to determine whether or not the columns are linearly independent, the answer is, yes, they are. That's so because there is a maximal square submatrix whose determinant is not $0$: take the matrix which consists of the first $3$ lines. Here, I say that a square submatrix is *maximal* if there are no larger square submatrices.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of linear independence: Consider an arbitrary linear combination $$a(1,0,0,0)+b(0,1,0,0)+c(0,0,1,0)=(a,b,c,0)$$ of the columns of this matrix. The only way for this to equal the zero vector is for $a=b=c=0$, therefore the columns are linearly independent.